# Use relation to apply same colour to children feature

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, symbology

I'm looking for a function with field calculator in a symbology context to apply the colour of parents features to the children with transparency.

Answer (score 1):

No existing function gets colour from parents using *relations*

### Parents layer

1. create 3 fields for RGB in

   `colour_r = rand(0,255)
   colour_g = rand(0,255)
   colour_b = rand(0,255)`
2. In symbology fill field calculator

   `color_rgb(  "color_r" , "color_g" , "color_b" )`

### Children layer

1. Children features have a foreign key `(_fk_)` to refer to the parent primary `(_pk_)` key in the parent layer. Here, it's `_id_ws_`
2. Add this in fill symbology field calculator with alpha canal

`color_rgba(
    attribute(get_feature('Parents_layer_name.shp','id_ws_pk',"id_ws_fk"),'color_r'),
        attribute(get_feature('Parents_layer_name.shp','id_ws_pk',"id_ws_fk"),'color_g'),
        attribute(get_feature('Parents_layer_name.shp','id_ws_pk',"id_ws_fk"),'color_b'),
        50
        )`

Comment: better solution?

Comment: You can simplify this approach by combining the RGB values into a string like `[r,g,b]`. Store it in a single field called 'color'. Then you only have to pull a single attribute into the symbology expression builder, like this: `attribute(get_feature('Parents_layer_name.shp','id_ws_pk',"id_ws_fk"),'color')`

Comment: You can create the color field in one step, with an expression like: `concat( '[', rand(0,255), rand(0,255), rand(0,255), ']' )`